Share data between aiohttp routes.view
I have setup an aiohttp web server. I want to save a user data in one of my URLs and then have access to this variable everywhere else; other URLS and different methods of the same URL (GET vs POST). This id will be unique for each user so I cannot use self.request.app.
I have been trying to use aiohttp_session, but cannot figure it out. Any help would be appreciated.
# __init__.py
async def creat_server():
    app = Application()

    app["db"] = await connect_to_mongodb()

    app.middlewares.append(db_middleware)

    fernet_key = fernet.Fernet.generate_key()
    secret_key = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(fernet_key)

    app.router.add_static("/static", os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "static"))
    aiohttp_jinja2.setup(
        app,
        loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(
            os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "templates")
        ),
    )
    setup_routes(app)
    setup(app, EncryptedCookieStorage(secret_key))

    return app

# views.py
@routes.view("/login")
class Login(web.View):
    async def get(self):
        object_id = await init_user(self.request.app["db"])
        session = await get_session(self.request)
        session["object_id"] = object_id
        print("\n\nhere0", session["object_id"], "\n\n")
        return FileResponse(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "login.html"))

    async def post(self):
        data = await self.request.post()
        phone_number = data.get("phone", "")
        session = await get_session(self.request)

        print("\n\nhere1:", session.get("object_id"), "\n\n")
        print("Phone number submitted:", phone_number)
        # add_phone(self.request.app['db'], self.object_id, self.request.form["phone"])
        return web.HTTPFound("/welcome-policy")


@routes.view("/welcome-policy")
class WelcomePolicy(web.View):
    async def get(self):
        return FileResponse(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "welcome-policy.html"))


The session["object_id"] is available in the get protion of Login page but not in the post method. When the user hits the /login page, they will see a form and when they submit the form, my HTML file will call the /login POST request and the session that I access in the post function seems to be different than that of the get.

As you are using cookies, you should first check if the browser is actually receiving and saving the cookies. The SimpleCookieStorage should be used for debugging, as you'll be able to see exactly what is being saved in the browser. Otherwise, will likely need a full reproducer (i.e. a file we can copy and just run) in order to debug further.

@SamBull I found a workaround but I still don't understand why the original code failed.
The problem is with returning FileResponse for the first view. I introduced a dummy URL to initialize the user_information in my DB and the return is HTTPFound to my /login page. From here on, the session information is saved properly. You can test this on any code, if the first return of the web_server is a FileResponse, the session information gets messed up. Any ideas why?
Also, I'm pretty new to aiohttp. How should I use SimpleCookieStorage?

I used the "inspect" of the browser and looked into the Cookies. If the first URL is returning an HTML file, the AIOHTTP_SESSION variable is never saved!

Ah, yes, forgot about that issue: https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp-session/issues/640

I would note that the typical way to render a page in aiohttp would be to return the contents directly, rather than a FileResponse (i.e. for reasonable performance, I'd read that file into memory on startup and just return the contents). If you need any templating (e.g. to display the user name), then aiohttp-jinja2 is the most common tool used for rendering HTML pages.

Thanks for sharing the link. I do use aiohttp_jinja2.render_template whenever I need to pass data to the HTML file.
your suggestion is always use the render rather than using FileResponse. I'm not sure what "read that file into memory on startup and just return the contents" really means and how it works since I'm very new to aiottp.
Thank you so much for your help.

I mean, just read the file beforehand: INDEX_BODY = Path("index.html").read_text(). Then just send the content in the handler: web.Response(text=INDEX_BODY). But, if you're already using aiohttp-jinja2, then I'd consider just using that for everything. It should handle caching the files in memory for you automatically (also, as you end up wanting common headers etc. across pages, you'll probably want to use the templates in order to reuse HTML blocks on every page anyway).
